# delphi2010 RestServer no Delete method

Tags: rest, delphi-2010, http-delete

I'm creating small REST server application.
Sending information via JSON.

But I have a problem because in my Delphi 2010 there is no DELETE type. There are only TMethodType = (mtAny, mtGet, mtPut, mtPost, mtHead);

How can I add the Delete method support?

Comment: `mtDelete` was added to `TMethodType` in XE7.

Comment: When receiving a request whose method cannot be encoded to `TMethodType`, the `TWebRequest.MethodType` will be `myAny`. Use the `TWebRequest.Method` property to get the actual method name as a `string`.